# aws lambda container images invocation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to learn how to deploy container based aws solutions, and I am going through the 101 tutorial here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/

I do seem to understand what is stated on the page, but I am baffled by this testing, where they make a curl post:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

Although it works, but I am really baffled by these dates: `2015-03-31` If I change this, it does not work! I have been thinking and digging around for more than 3 hours now, but I am not able to figure out what these dates mean :(

In reality, I dont think I understand how this url of curl, relates to the docker image.. confused!

Comment: That's the Lambda API version. Example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html.

Comment: Ah! Damn! waste of ~180mins :(

Comment: I just added it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of notation is usual for different types of resources in AWS, e.g., policies, but in this case it is related to the Lambda API version. One example for JavaScript:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html